# Xubuntu 12.10 and FFMPEG webcam

Tags: webcam, ffmpeg, video4linux

Having a problem running `ffmpeg` to an `ffserver` in a **brand new** install of Xubuntu 12.10.

I just installed Xubuntu 12.10 from scratch, then installed ffmpeg. I plugged in my webcam (mind you I have used this webcam on another system Ubuntu 12.04 and 11.04 without any problems using the same `ffserver` and same command) then ran the ffmpeg command:

```
ffmpeg -f video4linux2 -i /dev/video0 http://IP:8090/cam1.ffm
```

Now in theory that should work but what I get is:

```
fmpeg version 0.8.4-6:0.8.4-0ubuntu0.12.10.1, Copyright (c) 2000-2012 the Libav developers
  built on Nov  6 2012 16:49:20 with gcc 4.7.2
*** THIS PROGRAM IS DEPRECATED ***
This program is only provided for compatibility and will be removed in a future release. Please use avconv instead.
ffmpeg: /build/buildd/libav-0.8.4/libavutil/mathematics.c:79: av_rescale_rnd: Assertion `c > 0' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I have searched that error and cannot find it anywhere. So I tried mplayer to see if the webcam was working and if `video0` was working:

```
mplayer tv:// -tv device=/dev/video0:driver=v4l2:width=352:height=288
```

That works perfectly and shows me my webcam screen.

Now I thought, ok maybe this stupid deprecation thing has something to do with it, so I tried the exact same command for ffmpeg using avconv and I get the same error.

`lsusb` gives me:

```
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04fc:1528 Sunplus Technology Co., Ltd SPCA1527A/SPCA1528 SD card camera (webcam mode)
```

As I said, I have this exact same webcam working on two other PC's with two different Ubuntu installs.

**EDIT:**

I've recompiled `ffmpeg` using these instructions:
https://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/UbuntuCompilationGuide

It works, if I just use the same command as above it runs, CPU runs at 100% as if it was converting. But no output in `ffmpeg`, it just hangs here indefinitely until I `ctrl-c`:

```
ffmpeg version git-2013-01-01-fde1305 Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Jan  1 2013 11:42:21 with gcc 4.7 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.2-2ubuntu1)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-libass --enable-libfaac --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-librtmp --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-x11grab --enable-libx264 --enable-nonfree --enable-version3
  libavutil      52. 13.100 / 52. 13.100
  libavcodec     54. 85.100 / 54. 85.100
  libavformat    54. 58.102 / 54. 58.102
  libavdevice    54.  3.102 / 54.  3.102
  libavfilter     3. 30.102 /  3. 30.102
  libswscale      2.  1.103 /  2.  1.103
  libswresample   0. 17.102 /  0. 17.102
  libpostproc    52.  2.100 / 52.  2.100
[video4linux2,v4l2 @ 0x97c8200] DTS discontinuity in stream 0: packet 3 with DTS 21527529506, packet 4 with DTS 21527577460
```

Then once I `ctrl-c` twice I get this:

```
^CEstimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
Input #0, video4linux2,v4l2, from '/dev/video0':
  Duration: N/A, start: 21527.513483, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p, 320x240, -2147483 kb/s, 18.08 tbr, 1000k tbn, 1000k tbc
http://IP:8090/cam1.ffm: Input/output error
Received signal 2: terminating.
```

Ok, let me see if I specify framerate what happens:

```
ffmpeg -r 2 -f video4linux2 -i /dev/video0 http://IP:8090/cam1.ffm

ffmpeg version git-2013-01-01-fde1305 Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Jan  1 2013 11:42:21 with gcc 4.7 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.2-2ubuntu1)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-libass --enable-libfaac --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-librtmp --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-x11grab --enable-libx264 --enable-nonfree --enable-version3
  libavutil      52. 13.100 / 52. 13.100
  libavcodec     54. 85.100 / 54. 85.100
  libavformat    54. 58.102 / 54. 58.102
  libavdevice    54.  3.102 / 54.  3.102
  libavfilter     3. 30.102 /  3. 30.102
  libswscale      2.  1.103 /  2.  1.103
  libswresample   0. 17.102 /  0. 17.102
  libpostproc    52.  2.100 / 52.  2.100
[video4linux2,v4l2 @ 0xa5fa2a0] DTS discontinuity in stream 0: packet 3 with DTS 21627329870, packet 4 with DTS 21627409821
[video4linux2,v4l2 @ 0xa5fa2a0] max_analyze_duration 5000000 reached at 5000000
[video4linux2,v4l2 @ 0xa5fa2a0] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
Input #0, video4linux2,v4l2, from '/dev/video0':
  Duration: N/A, start: 21627.313851, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p, 320x240, 0 kb/s, 2 fps, 0.25 tbr, 1000k tbn, 2 tbc
Incompatible pixel format '(null)' for codec 'flv', auto-selecting format '(null)'
    Last message repeated 1 times
[flv @ 0xa6046c0] Specified pixel format yuvj420p is invalid or not supported
Output #0, ffm, to 'http://198.144.186.224:8090/cam1.ffm':
  Metadata:
    creation_time   : now
    Stream #0:0: Video: flv1 ([0][0][0][5] / 0x5000000), yuvj420p, 320x2, q=255-255, 200 kb/s, 1000k tbn, 2 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mjpeg -> flv)
Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
```

My `ffserver` conf file looks like this (even though as I said it was working before from another PC):

```
Port 8090
BindAddress IP
MaxHTTPConnections 30
MaxClients 20
MaxBandwidth 2000
CustomLog - 

<Feed cam1.ffm> 
File /tmp/cam1.ffm
FileMaxSize 10000K
</Feed> 

<Stream cam1.flv> 
Feed cam1.ffm 
Format flv 
VideoCodec flv 
VideoFrameRate 2
VideoBufferSize 20000 
VideoBitRate 200 
VideoQMin 5
VideoQMax 10 
VideoSize qvga
PreRoll 0 
Noaudio 
AVOptionVideo flags +global_header
</Stream>

<Stream stat.html>
Format status
</Stream>
```

**EDIT 2:**

Just confirmed that running it on my Ubuntu 11.04 machine it works just fine, the command is a bit different but it works:

```
ffmpeg -r 10 -s 320x240 -f video4linux2 -aspect 4:3 -i /dev/video0 http://IP:8090/cam1.ffm
```

So I copied this command into the other Xubuntu system and I get the `missing yuvj420p` problem from before:

```
[video4linux2,v4l2 @ 0xb1c53e0] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
Input #0, video4linux2,v4l2, from '/dev/video0':
  Duration: N/A, start: 27867.321194, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p, 320x240, -1 kb/s, 10 tbr, 1000k tbn, 10 tbc
Incompatible pixel format '(null)' for codec 'flv', auto-selecting format '(null)'
    Last message repeated 1 times
[flv @ 0xb1ca6e0] Specified pixel format yuvj420p is invalid or not supported
Output #0, ffm, to 'http://198.144.186.224:8090/cam1.ffm':
  Metadata:
    creation_time   : now
    Stream #0:0: Video: flv1 ([0][0][0][5] / 0x5000000), yuvj420p, 320x10, q=255-255, 200 kb/s, 1000k tbn, 10 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mjpeg -> flv)
Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
```

Above is posted the config information when I run `ffmpeg` on my Xubuntu machine, here is what is displayed when I run `ffmpeg` on my Ubuntu 11 machine:

```
FFmpeg version 0.6.6-4:0.6.6-0ubuntu0.11.04.1, Copyright (c) 2000-2010 the Libav developers
  built on Jun 12 2012 16:28:21 with gcc 4.5.2
  configuration: --extra-version=4:0.6.6-0ubuntu0.11.04.1 --prefix=/usr --enable-avfilter --enable-avfilter-lavf --enable-vdpau --enable-bzlib --enable-libgsm --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-pthreads --enable-zlib --enable-libvpx --disable-stripping --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-vaapi --enable-gpl --enable-postproc --enable-swscale --enable-x11grab --enable-libdc1394 --enable-shared --disable-static
  WARNING: library configuration mismatch
  libavutil   configuration: --extra-version=4:0.6.6-1ubuntu1 --prefix=/usr --enable-avfilter --enable-avfilter-lavf --enable-vdpau --enable-bzlib --enable-libdirac --enable-libgsm --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-pthreads --enable-zlib --enable-libvpx --disable-stripping --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-vaapi --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-gpl --enable-postproc --enable-swscale --enable-x11grab --enable-libfaad --enable-libdirac --enable-libfaad --enable-libmp3lame --enable-librtmp --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-libdc1394 --shlibdir=/usr/lib/i686/cmov --cpu=i686 --enable-shared --disable-static --disable-ffmpeg --disable-ffplay
  libavcodec  configuration: --extra-version=4:0.6.6-1ubuntu1 --prefix=/usr --enable-avfilter --enable-avfilter-lavf --enable-vdpau --enable-bzlib --enable-libdirac --enable-libgsm --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-pthreads --enable-zlib --enable-libvpx --disable-stripping --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-vaapi --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-gpl --enable-postproc --enable-swscale --enable-x11grab --enable-libfaad --enable-libdirac --enable-libfaad --enable-libmp3lame --enable-librtmp --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-libdc1394 --shlibdir=/usr/lib/i686/cmov --cpu=i686 --enable-shared --disable-static --disable-ffmpeg --disable-ffplay
  libavformat configuration: --extra-version=4:0.6.6-0ubuntu0.11.04.1 --prefix=/usr --enable-avfilter --enable-avfilter-lavf --enable-vdpau --enable-bzlib --enable-libgsm --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-pthreads --enable-zlib --enable-libvpx --disable-stripping --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-vaapi --enable-gpl --enable-postproc --enable-swscale --enable-x11grab --enable-libdc1394 --shlibdir=/usr/lib/i686/cmov --cpu=i686 --enable-shared --disable-static --disable-ffmpeg --disable-ffplay
  libavdevice configuration: --extra-version=4:0.6.6-0ubuntu0.11.04.1 --prefix=/usr --enable-avfilter --enable-avfilter-lavf --enable-vdpau --enable-bzlib --enable-libgsm --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-pthreads --enable-zlib --enable-libvpx --disable-stripping --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-vaapi --enable-gpl --enable-postproc --enable-swscale --enable-x11grab --enable-libdc1394 --shlibdir=/usr/lib/i686/cmov --cpu=i686 --enable-shared --disable-static --disable-ffmpeg --disable-ffplay
  libavfilter configuration: --extra-version=4:0.6.6-0ubuntu0.11.04.1 --prefix=/usr --enable-avfilter --enable-avfilter-lavf --enable-vdpau --enable-bzlib --enable-libgsm --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-pthreads --enable-zlib --enable-libvpx --disable-stripping --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-vaapi --enable-gpl --enable-postproc --enable-swscale --enable-x11grab --enable-libdc1394 --shlibdir=/usr/lib/i686/cmov --cpu=i686 --enable-shared --disable-static --disable-ffmpeg --disable-ffplay
  libswscale  configuration: --extra-version=4:0.6.6-0ubuntu0.11.04.1 --prefix=/usr --enable-avfilter --enable-avfilter-lavf --enable-vdpau --enable-bzlib --enable-libgsm --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-pthreads --enable-zlib --enable-libvpx --disable-stripping --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-vaapi --enable-gpl --enable-postproc --enable-swscale --enable-x11grab --enable-libdc1394 --shlibdir=/usr/lib/i686/cmov --cpu=i686 --enable-shared --disable-static --disable-ffmpeg --disable-ffplay
  libpostproc configuration: --extra-version=4:0.6.6-0ubuntu0.11.04.1 --prefix=/usr --enable-avfilter --enable-avfilter-lavf --enable-vdpau --enable-bzlib --enable-libgsm --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-pthreads --enable-zlib --enable-libvpx --disable-stripping --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-vaapi --enable-gpl --enable-postproc --enable-swscale --enable-x11grab --enable-libdc1394 --shlibdir=/usr/lib/i686/cmov --cpu=i686 --enable-shared --disable-static --disable-ffmpeg --disable-ffplay
  libavutil     50.15. 1 / 50.15. 1
  libavcodec    52.72. 2 / 52.72. 2
  libavformat   52.64. 2 / 52.64. 2
  libavdevice   52. 2. 0 / 52. 2. 0
  libavfilter    1.19. 0 /  1.19. 0
  libswscale     0.11. 0 /  0.11. 0
  libpostproc   51. 2. 0 / 51. 2. 0
```

So of course it's compiled with different options, but which option is the one that supports `yuvj420p` or how do I get the error for that to go away now that I know what the problem "seems" to be?

**EDIT 3:**

I recompiled using my switches from my working Ubuntu 11 system:

```
./configure --enable-gpl --enable-libass --enable-libfaac --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libmp3lame   --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-librtmp --enable-libtheora   --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-x11grab --enable-libx264 --enable-nonfree --enable-version3 --enable-shared --enable-libv4l2 --enable-avfilter --enable-vdpau --enable-bzlib --enable-libgsm --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-pthreads --enable-zlib --disable-stripping --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-vaapi --enable-gpl --enable-postproc --enable-swscale --enable-libdc1394 --disable-static
```

The `--enable-shared` is supposed to be `yuvj` subsets.

So that's done and all switches, now I run it and get:

```
[video4linux2,v4l2 @ 0x9d1d0e0] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
Input #0, video4linux2,v4l2, from '/dev/video0':
  Duration: N/A, start: 36365.493926, bitrate: 36863 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (I420 / 0x30323449), yuv420p, 640x480, 36863 kb/s, 10 tbr, 1000k tbn, 10 tbc
Incompatible pixel format '(null)' for codec 'flv', auto-selecting format '(null)'
    Last message repeated 1 times
[flv @ 0x9d22440] Warning min_rate > 0 but min_rate != max_rate isn't recommended!
[flv @ 0x9d22440] bitrate below min bitrate
Output #0, ffm, to 'http://IP:8090/cam1.ffm':
  Metadata:
    creation_time   : now
    Stream #0:0: Video: flv1 ([0][0][0][5] / 0x5000000), yuv420p, 640x10, q=255-255, 200 kb/s, 1000k tbn, 10 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (rawvideo -> flv)
Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
```

So now it runs and finds things but still won't let me because of `bitrate below min bitrate`. I have tried setting `-b 200k` and `-b 600k` but still same thing. I figure it's because the FFM file states 200, but I want it at 200.

So now how do I disable bitrate checking?

I guess that's the problem now, to be honest I'm tempted to install Ubuntu 11.04 on this system and scratch it, each new version of software makes things harder and harder.